# Unable to retrieve images from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I made a table in my database using mysql and inserted my image there but i can't retrieve it on my php file.Here is my php file:

```
<?php
    
require_once "dbconfig.php";
$select_stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM product"); 
$select_stmt->execute();
while($row=$select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
    <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="images/<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>"</a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title text-primary"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?> </h4>
              <h5><?php echo number_format($row['product_price'],2); ?>/-</h5>
          </div>
      
          <div class="card-footer">
      <form class="form-submit">
        <input type="hidden" class="pid" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="pname" value="<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="pprice" value="<?php echo $row['product_price']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="pimage" value="<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="pcode" value="<?php echo $row['product_code']; ?>">
        <button id="addItem" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Add to Cart</button>
      </form>
          </div>
```

Also my image is in the same directory as my file so i don't get where is my error. Here is how my i wrote it in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
    product_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    product_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    product_price varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    product_image varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    product_code varchar(10) NOT NULL
)
```

I stored my image using insert query, I forgot to add it. I wrote it like this in mysql:

```
INSERT INTO product (product_id, product_name, product_price, product_image, product_code) 
VALUES (1, 'laptop', '200', 'laptop.jpg', 'p1000'),
```

Comment: SO how do you store you `product_image varchar(255) NOT NULL,` I assume its a filename, or path and filename?

Comment: Normally all you need to know to add a product to a Cart, is the key to the product row, I assume that would be `product_id int(11) NOT NULL,`

Comment: DId you look at your product table to make sure the the `product_image` column has something useful in it?

Comment: I stored my image using insert query, I forgot to add it. I wrote it like this in mysql: INSERT INTO `product` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `product_price`, `product_image`, `product_code`) VALUES
(1, 'laptop', '200', 'laptop.jpg', 'p1000'),

Comment: Info like that belongs in the question not as a comment, use the EDIT link to add to your question when asked for more info in comments

Comment: "`<a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="images/<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>"</a>`"You're missing a closing `>` on that image tag.  "`'laptop.jpg',`" so for that entry to the database exist, then relative to the script you show, must exist `images/laptop.jpg`.  When you say "image is in the same directory as my file" sounds like it's not in `./images/` but just in `./`

Comment: "i can't retrieve it on my php file" if you go into your browser and pull up the developer tools, you should be able to see the failed request for `images/japtop.jpg` which results in a 404.  Those developer tools are going to be one of your best friends for web development, so get to know them

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really helpful. My images are showing on my webpage now

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code that is there missing closing angle bracket in the line where you display the image:

```
<a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="images/<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>"</a>
```

Change to below

```
<a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="images/<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>"></a>
```

#### Still issue follow below debug steps

1. Also, make sure that the image file has the correct permissions and is not corrupted.
2. Make sure that the image file path is correct
3. Double-check that the file name in the database matches the actual file name.